# Cargar un Carousel (bootstrap) con imagenes en una coleccion

Tags: bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy queriendo mostrar mas de una imagen en un artículo, utilizando un carousel. Sí o sí muestra una (imagen principal), y con un limite de 5 fotos

En si el carousel no es el problema, el tema es la coleccion donde tengo las x imagenes. Probando a prueba y error, llegue a la conclusión que necesito un item activo. Asi que muestro la primera imagen con first() y luego recorreria la coleccion, mostrando las demás imágenes.

El problema es que no puedo hacer q la coleccion se mueva al siguiente objeto para empezar a recorrerlo

Por lo que leí las colecciones no tienen un next() o algo asi. Aquí dejo el codigo

```
<div id="mi-carousel" class="carousel slide">        

          <!-- Contenedor de los Slide -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$articulo->imagenes->first()->nombre) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
            </div>
                @foreach($articulo->imagenes as $imagen)                    
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$imagen->nombre) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                    </div>
                @endforeach
        </div>

          <!-- Controloles -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mi-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mi-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Siguiente hidden-xs hidden-sd</span>
          </a>
    </div>
```

Así como esta, muestra la primer imagen 2 veces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te muestro dos formas de hacer que la primera imagen aparezca solo una vez:

Método shift() en una colección, el cual utiliza el primer elemento de la misma y lo elimina de la colección:

```
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$articulo->imagenes->shift()->nombre) }}" class="img-responsive" alt="" >
        </div>
            @foreach($articulo->imagenes as $imagen)                    
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$imagen->nombre) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Usando alguna forma de determinar el primer elemento con php "puro" para agregar la clase active:

```
            @foreach($articulo->imagenes as $index => $imagen)                    
                <div class="item @if($index == 0) active @endif">
                    <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$imagen->nombre) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola esta solución es la correcta tarde en encontrarla pero esta corre de manera correcta sin errores subo las dos imagenes, la del controlador y como queda el slider, se utiliza una variable $loop que tienen los @foreach para encontrar los index y activar el campo si es el primero.

[introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EhBP.png)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CARGA DEL CONTROLADOR BUSQUEDA DE LOS ARCHIVOS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos evita poner codigo con imagenes no es facil para transcribirle

Answer (score -1):

Hola yo lo soluciones desde el controlador primero paso una consulta con un valor y luego paso la que lleva todos.

```
public function index(){
    $slideruno=Slider::find(1);
    $sliders=Slider::orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
    // dd($slider);
    return view('sliders.slider',compact('sliders','slideruno'));
}
```

y en la vista quedaria asi, se que no es lo correcto pero es la única manera que encontré hasta ahorita.

```
<div class="carousel-item active">              
    <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ Voyager::image( $slideruno->imagen ) }}" alt="First slide"> 
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo, no coloques imágenes en tu respuesta si puedes colocar el código, por si no lo has hecho realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para una mejor compresión de como funciona el sitio